# Multiply two large numbers in under 1000 instructions using reduced ISA with only 7 registers

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, intuition, binary

Is it possible to multiply two large (15 bit) numbers efficiently (in under 1000 instructions) using the following ISA:

```
add          //add <reg1> <reg2> <reg3>: add contents of registers 1 and 2 and store in register 3
nand         //nand <reg1> <reg2> <reg3>: nand (negated logical and) contents of registers 1 and 2 and store in register 3
beq          //beq <reg1> <reg2> <label>: if the contents of registers 1 and 2 are equal, jump to label
load         //load <reg2> <label>: load reg2 with content from label
nope         //nope: do nothing
halt         //halt: end program
occupy       //<label> occupy off: label will take value off (between -32768 and 32767)
```

The memory addresses are 0-indexed, and any occupy statements must come after a halt.  For example, a valid program may be:

```
        load    0    1    ten    //register1 = 10
        load    1    2    m1     //register2 = -1
here    add     1    1    1      //register1 = register1+register1 = 20
        beq     0    0    end    //if(register0 = register0), go to end
end     halt
ten     occupy  10
m1      occupy  -1
```

I know there are efficient methods using binary multiplication (and the nand operator, presumably), but I'm having trouble constructing a program that can multiply large integers accurately.

Any ideas?

If there is anything that needs to be clarified, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this is a better fit for the computing site?

Comment: I haven't received much insight there, so I thought I would try here.

Comment: Could you post the link to your stackoverflow post?

Comment: @JacobSchlather it was closed as "non constructive."  However, I've edited the details here.  Efficiency seems to be harder to achieve in this program (since adding multiple times takes much too long).

Comment: Can you not implement the usual algorithm for multiplication you learned in elementary school?

Comment: @Hurkyl, it takes much too long (for example, multiplying 5000*8000 would require at least 5000 instructions-- adding 8000 to itself).

Comment: @Bob: The usual algorithm isn't repeated addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.  For clarity I refer to registers by letters instead of numbers, and use expression notation to write the instructions.  The expression "p # q" means the negated AND of p and q.

```
; Computes the product of nonnegative integers a and b and stores it in s
z <- 0                          ; z == 0
s <- 0                          ; stores the product
j <- 1                          ; a power of 2, determines which bit of b
                                ; the program is looking at
c <- a + z                      ; c == a * j

loop:
  if b == z goto endprogram       ; end if there are no 
                                  ; remaining bits in b
  d <- j # b
  d <- d # d                      ; d == j & b       
  if d == z goto noadd
    s <- s + c                    ; the bit determined by j is set in b,
                                  ; so add c to the product s
  noadd: 
  d <- j # j
  b <- b # d
  b <- b # b                      ; b := b & ~j         
  j <- j + j                      ; j := 2j
  c <- c + c                      ; c := 2c
  if z == z goto loop
endprogram:
halt
```